# Solving simple circuit problem

Tags: circuit-analysis

Could someone show me the methodology to solve the following problem?

If the resistance of a circuit having 12 V source is increased by 4 Ω, the current drops by 0.5 A. What is the original resistance of the circuit?

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange.  Be sure to take the tour to get the most out of this site:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/Tour

Answer (score 2):

You are told that the current with R is more than the current with R and some added resistance by a specified amount. So write this very simple English statement down as an equation:

$$\begin{align*}
I_{R}-I_{R+4\:\Omega}&=500\:\textrm{mA}\\\\
\end{align*}$$

But you also know Ohm's law. So, just replace the currents by the obvious fractions to find:

$$\begin{align*}
I_{R}-I_{R+4\:\Omega}&=500\:\textrm{mA}\\\\
\frac{12\:\textrm{V}}{R}-\frac{12\:\textrm{V}}{R+4\:\Omega}&=500\:\textrm{mA}
\end{align*}$$

And solve for \$R\$.

Hopefully, you can see how you start by just writing down what you read with the simplest possible quantitative statement about it, and then follow it up by filling in more details until you can see something that looks as though it is solvable. Then you solve it.

---

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{12\:\textrm{V}}{R}-\frac{12\:\textrm{V}}{R+4\:\Omega}&=500\:\textrm{mA} \\\\
12\:\textrm{V}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{R+4\:\Omega}\right)&=500\:\textrm{mA} \\\\
12\:\textrm{V}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{R+4\:\Omega}\right)\cdot R\cdot \left(R+4\:\Omega\right)&=500\:\textrm{mA}\cdot R\cdot \left(R+4\:\Omega\right) \\\\
12\:\textrm{V}\cdot \left(\frac{R\cdot \left(R+4\:\Omega\right)}{R}-\frac{R\cdot \left(R+4\:\Omega\right)}{R+4\:\Omega}\right)&=500\:\textrm{mA}\cdot R\cdot \left(R+4\:\Omega\right) \\\\
12\:\textrm{V}\cdot \left(R+4\:\Omega-R\right)&=500\:\textrm{mA}\cdot R\cdot \left(R+4\:\Omega\right) \\\\
500\:\textrm{mA}\cdot R\cdot \left(R+4\:\Omega\right)&=12\:\textrm{V}\cdot 4\:\Omega \\\\
R\cdot \left(R+4\:\Omega\right)&=\frac{12\:\textrm{V}\cdot 4\:\Omega}{500\:\textrm{mA}}= 96\:\Omega^2 \\\\
R^2+4\:\Omega\cdot R&= 96\:\Omega^2 \\\\
R^2+4\:\Omega\cdot R&- 96\:\Omega^2 = 0
\end{align*}$$

That's a quadratic equation form (\$a\:R^2+b\:R+c=0\$), where \$a=1\$, \$b=4\$, and \$c=-96\$. That is solvable:

$$\begin{align*}
R&=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4\: a\: c}}{2\: a}\\\\
&=\frac{-4\pm\sqrt{4^2-4\cdot 1\cdot -96}}{2\cdot 1}\\\\
&=\frac{-4\pm\sqrt{400}}{2}\\\\
&=\frac{-4\pm 20}{2}\\\\
&=-2\pm 10\\\\
\end{align*}$$

And there is only one realistic value there, which is \$R=8\:\Omega\$.

Comment: Hey, nice answer :)

Comment: @uint128_t Cripes. Same thoughts, same steps, same moment... Oh, well. I did write more words!! ;) [Which may be for better or for worse.] Hopefully, the OP will follow along.

Comment: Aye, you've got a more helpful explanation, I think.

Comment: @uint128_t But a focus on just the math might be better. ;) Plus, you wrote out the fractions, independently, and I just stuffed them in directly. All depends on the recipient, I suppose. :)

Comment: I can compute the answer from this equation by trial and error, but can you show me how you would solve for R mathematically.

Comment: @user149462 Yes. But the fact you need the help means you definitely need to buckle down and become fluent with algebraic manipulation. It's okay to be in a process of learning. But I want you to keep in mind that without that fluency, electronics will be out of your reach. It's a crucial, fundamental skill. I don't mind adding the explanation. I just want you to know that it is important that you master it on your own.

Answer (score 2):

I have a different approach.

### very useful to learn for each type of chemistry in future

In all batteries and capacitors we know there is always some finite effective  series resistance or ESR which is measured by incremental changes so we can call it ΔR

### Ohms law is useful for incremental changes too.

ESR= ΔR = ΔV/ΔI

- meaning a rise in current with a drop in voltage for batteries
- or for LEDs (when On) a rise in voltage with almost linear rise in current.

Now back to the question.

- using the question values

  - ΔR= + 4 Ω
  - ΔI = -0.5A
  - so ΔV =  -2V
    ( so R_initial must have 10V across it,@ 0.5A)

### So what is R?

Answer (score 1):

$$I_{NEW} = I_{OLD}-0.5\text{ A}$$
where
$$I_{OLD} = \frac{12\text{ V}}{R_X}$$
and
$$I_{NEW} = \frac{12\text{ V}}{R_X + 4\text{ }\Omega}$$

See [Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law).